# Increment of dereferenced pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Why does the following piece

```
char *arr[] = {"C", "C++", "Java", "VBA"};
char *(*ptr)[4] = &arr;
printf("%s\n", ++(*ptr)[2]);
printf("%s\n", ++(*ptr)[2]);
printf("%s\n", ++(*ptr)[2]);
```

outputs

> ava
>   va
>   a

I can't figure out why and where the information that dereferenced `ptr` is incremented is kept. Debugger tells me that `(*ptr)[2]` is indeed incremented, and `ptr` stays unchanged, but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: `arr[2]` is what's incrementing.

Comment: Could you please add some more patentheses and `*`s to the declarations to make your code even more complicated? Why not `char **ptr = arr;` and use simpler expressions in the `printf`s? What do you want to achive? What is the expected result? What does the debugger show about your array?

Answer (score 1):

The array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the preincrement operator `++`.  So the expression is effectively:

```
++((*ptr)[2])
```

As for where the increment is stored, your array `arr` is an array of pointers, each pointing to a string literal.  When you increment `(*ptr)[2]` the value of this pointer is incremented by 1, so it points to the next character in the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Memory map for understanding]

[image: memory map of string JAVA]

`Ptr` is a pointer to array. `&a` is pointing to address of whole array, so when you do `&a+1` whole size of array gets incremented.
Now, when we do `*ptr`, it means now it is pointng to first element of array i.e. ptr contains the address of 1st element of array i.e. 1000 .
Now, [ ] operator increments the address to that location, so `(*ptr)[2]` is equivalent to  1000 +2 (pointer addition) i.e. 1008 .
Now we are at 1008 location and applying `++`, so this will act on its memory that contain the address 300, will become 301 (because `JAVA` is string that each element in string takes 1 byte space in memory, so character pointer gets incremented 1 byte only.), so it prints the "ava" . Now, apply same with other calls.